# What might be wrong with Spring Security Config? Get vs POST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have a Rest Controller and two endpoints there. While I can do basic authentication to GET end endpoint, I can not perform the same for the POST endpoint.

Please see the curl executions for GET and POST below, for some reason POST endpoint returns 401.

What might be the reason? Any ideas? As you can check in Security Config at bottom, I do not have special cases for GET/POST.

GET TRY:

```
curl -v -u user:password -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/clusters/
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> GET /api/clusters/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Fri, 20 Dec 2019 12:50:44 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
[{"id":1,"name":"Alfa","securityProtocol":"PLAINTEXT","sslTruststorePassword":null,"sslKeystorePassword":null,"sslKeyPassword":null,"trustStore":null,"keyStore":null,"saslMechanism":"","saslJaasConfig":"","clientId":"Ali","requestTimeoutMs":30000,"version":0,"properties":[],"bootstrapServers":"kafka1:9093"}]* Closing connection 0
```

POST TRY:

```
kaan$ curl -v -u user:password -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/clusters/ -d {"name":"Beta"}
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> POST /api/clusters/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 11
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 11 out of 11 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 401 
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=022342C09075AC29AC703547FD5A0E45; Path=/; HttpOnly
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Fri, 20 Dec 2019 12:51:38 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

And my Security Config is as:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/vendor/**", "/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.html")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue:

.csrf().disable()